# How to exclude files from pub publish for Dart packages?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, dart-pub

Is there any way to exclude certain files or directories from `pub publish` for dart packages?

I am publishing a package that has so many screenshots. I want them to upload on GitHub but not on `Pub.Dev`. The intention behind this is to reduce the package size.

Answer (score 6):

You can now create a `.pubignore` file to do this. See [this PR](https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/pull/2787) for more details on how this works.

Answer (score 5):

Clearing git cache from my PC works for me:

`git rm -r --cached .`

Answer (score 0):

You can add them in `.gitignore` while publishing to `pub.dev` and later remove from `.gitignore` before pushing to `GitHub`.

Referenced from [dart documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/publishing#what-files-are-published).

> What files are published?
>   All files in your package are included in the published package, with the following exceptions:
>   Any packages directories.
>   Your package’s lockfile.
>   If you aren’t using Git, all hidden files (that is, files whose names begin with .).
>   If you’re using Git, any files ignored by your .gitignore file.
>   Be sure to delete any files you don’t want to include (or add them to .gitignore). pub publish lists all files that it’s going to publish before uploading your package, so examine the list carefully before completing your upload.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options to exclude files or directories from getting published to pub.dev.

1. Add your files or directories to `.pubignore` or `.gitignore` file.
2. Hide your file or directory by giving it a name which starts with a `.` (dot)
3. Create a new directory with `packages` name and put your files there.

If a directory contains both a `.pubignore` file and a `.gitignore` file, `dart pub publish` will not read that directory's `.gitignore` file i.e. you can overrule `.gitignore` file by creating a `.pubignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little on some of the existing answers, the [dart docs](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/publishing#what-files-are-published) state:

> All files under the package root directory are included in the published package, with the following exceptions:
>
> - Any hidden files or directories — that is, files with names that begin with dot (.)
> - Any directories with the name packages
> - Files and directories ignored by a .pubignore or .gitignore file

...

> (If a directory contains both a .pubignore file and a .gitignore file, then dart pub publish doesn’t read that directory’s .gitignore file.) The format of .pubignore files is the same as the .gitignore file format